# How index of working in string

Tags: java

Can any one tell me how indexOf method working in string?
I know how I use it and know what it give but I want to know how it work...  Coz I have a home work and teachers ask me to solve it with out using index and u need to use it to define the position of (.) in double number

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because either the documentation or the source code can give you the answer.

Comment: @demongolem  can u give me?  And I will thanks u

Comment: You should rephrase your question. You are looking for the decimal separator in a double, and digits in certain positions of a number. `String.indexOf` is only one way to work with those.

Answer (score 1):

you can do a linear search. If it's a parser, you can parse the input char by char.

EDIT:

In the comment you mention you are looking for special numbers in a double variable(?). is it stored in a string? if so you can use linear search as mentioned above.

```
//In your question it seems the strings are well fitted as [0..9]++[.]++[0..9]++
int indexOfFirstDigit = 0;
int indexOfLastDigit = input.length();
//so we only have to look for the decimal dot
int indexBeforeDec = 0;
int indexAfterDec = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < input.length();i++){
    char current = input.charAt(i);
    if(current == '.'){
        indexBeforeDec = i-1;
        indexAfterDec = i+1;
    }   
}
//Get the values with input.charAt() and the corresponding index
```

or do you have a already parsed double variable and want special digits?

```
int digitBeforeDec = (int)input%10;
int digitAfterDec = (int)(input*10) %10;
//firstDigit
int firstDigit;
int in = (int) input;
int mod = in%10;
while (mod != 0 && in > 10) {
    in /=10;
    mod = in%10;
}
firstDigit = mod;
//LastDigit is not that easy for reasons of inaccuracy in double representation.
```

The last digit is not that easy because of the doble representation in memory. most of the time you won't have the exact value in memory. Maybe a .ToString() call and the linear search from above would be sufficiant for you.

Comment: Write a program that read a double number like 786.45 and then find the following without index :  the first digit and the last digit   and the digit before decimal and digit after decimal

Comment: @Aghyad Edit your question to clarify. Do not add comments if you are not asking about an answer. Comments may not be shown initially, and another user trying to answer your question may not even see them.